# Citation with ACS style and superscript

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using biblatex and biber to generate my bibliography:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
```

but it doesn't look like proposed here: http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chem/biblatex-chem-acs.pdf

It rather looks like shown here: https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Biblatex_bibliography_styles

As I understood the style is set automatically. Does that mean it is the new standard ACS style or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

---

Thank you for the prompt answers and sorry for being unprecise. For the first link how I expected it so see it with the superscript and reference listing is as follows:

[image]

[image]

The second link provides how I have it in my thesis

[image]

Comment: The link you give to how it looks is not really helpful: that's a listing of all the standard styles. Can you edit in a picture of what you are seeing?

Comment: Interestingly [`biblatex-chem-acs.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chem/biblatex-chem-acs.tex) explicitly sets `\usepackage[style=chem-acs,biblabel=dot]{biblatex}` so it is not too surprising that the default output and the documentation differ. For superscript citations you should use `\autocite`, `\cite` still gives normal numbers.

Comment: @JosephWright ^^^^ I can't access JACS papers at the moment, my university's authentication system does not load, but I could find a few papers on the web and all of them have parentheses around the numbers in the bibliography, so the `biblabel=dot` in the call to `biblatex` in `biblatex-chem-acs.tex` should probably be removed: It only causes confusion.

Comment: @moewe The exact style depends on the journal: the ACS have over 30, each with it's own settings! This is one of the places they vary.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, but surely the output in the documentation should match the call as shown in the documentation. Currently `biblatex-chem-acs.tex` say to load `\usepackage[style=chem-acs]{biblatex}` but loads `\usepackage[style=chem-acs,biblabel=dot]{biblatex}` itself without mentioning that.

Comment: @Metamorphosis As I say: (i) Use `\autocite` instead of `\cite`. (ii) Either accept the parentheses (which are one of the styles accepted by the ACS and mandated for J. Am. Chem. Soc., but some other ACS journals, for example ACS Chem. Biol, use different settings, see https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG.ch014) or change the settings with `biblabel=dot` if you like that better.

Comment: @moewe Ah, right: I'm not sure why I have that anyway. For the next relaese!

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex-chem` does not modify the behaviour of `\cite`, it still gives a normal citation number (this is in line with what most other styles do as well). Ideally you should **use `\autocite`** to get citations as desired by the style, in case of `chem-acs` you then get superscript citations as desired. `\autocite` is at a higher level of abstraction because its behaviour can be changed with a simple option.

As mentioned in the comments the round parentheses you see in the bibliography are in compliance with the style required for the J. Am. Chem. Soc. The ACS also has some journals with a slightly different style that requires a dots after the numbers. The option `biblabel` can be used to control the format of the label number in the bibliography. The default settings of `chem-acs` give you the parentheses, but earlier versions of the style documentation [`biblatex-chem-acs.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chem/biblatex-chem-acs.pdf) would load `chem-acs` with the option `biblabel=dot` (from version 1.1v 2018-09-06 onward, `biblatex-chem`'s style documentations use the normal settings of their respective style).

The following MWE shows `chem-acs` with the settings for the J. Am. Chem. Soc.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem<sup>1</sup>\(1) Sigfridsson, E.; Ryde, U. Journal of Computational Chemistry 1998, 19, 377–395.]